# Не работает адаптивный размер текста в бутстрапе

Tags: css, bootstrap

В документации к бутстрапу 4 есть пример как сделать адаптивный размер 
https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.1/content/typography/

```css
html {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: А вопрос в чем? или это не вопрос а констатация факта?

Comment: И Вправду),я когда в ксс файл подставляю то оно не работает

Comment: Единица rem задаёт размер относительно размера шрифта элемента <html> меняйте в px

Comment: Неа не помогло,вот залил на хостингhttps://dfyz123123123123.000webhostapp.com/directory/index.html#,всё время один размер шрифта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код не будет работать напрямую из CSS. Его нужно вставлять в свой **SCSS** и компилировать. `@include media-breakpoint-up(md)` - это миксин бутстрапа.

Из CSS это делается так:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    html {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    html {
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }
}
```